# android.os.FileUriExposedException Error while generating download pdf

Tags: android

Not able to generate pdf download getting error of android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/INV-0002.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

```
       String path = downloadPDF();

        if (path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(NewInvoiceActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.pdf_not_created), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Because of missing _FileProvider_ in your code. For more info [check](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0)

Comment: try this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/9060917

Comment: See : [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed#answer-38858040)

Comment: String path = downloadPDF();
            Uri pdfURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "in.khushiuka.invoicing", new File(path));

            if (path.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(NewInvoiceActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.pdf_not_created), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(pdfURI, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: Getting error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score -1):

This occurs when your targetSdk version >=28
So use this lines in your activty/fragment in the onCreate() method to ignore the uri exposure

```
` StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

`

Comment: yes it is not an optiamal solution, the best solution is to create a custom file provider class... But when you need some quick hack..then this method works like a charm !